# How to implement Livestamp.js + Moment.js in my php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, livestamp.js

I am beginner and i am trying to implement [Livestamp.js](https://mattbradley.github.io/livestampjs/) + [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) in my website for user posts from past a month. Tried everything but not getting the results please help me.

Here is my **sql**

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

**Here is my results data get_data.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("db.php");
include("ssql.php");
if(isset($_GET['offset']) && isset($_GET['limit'])){
$limit = $_GET['limit'];
$offset = $_GET['offset'];  
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'xxxx');
$data = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `posts` DESC LIMIT {$limit} OFFSET {$offset} ");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    echo "<span data-livestamp=".$row['date']."></span>";   
}
}
?>
```

And here is Livestamp.js and Moment.js

```
<div id="post1">
     <script src="jquery.js"></script>
     <script src="moment.js"></script>
     <script src="livestamp.js"></script>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Livestamp.js uses **timestamped** data, as they've made it clear in their website:

> ...text to your timestamped HTML elements...

You might want to convert the datetime to timestamp like so:

```
strtotime($row['date'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. it helped me :)